# Boot Linux Mint 16 in graphical mode?

Tags: grub2

Linux Mint 16 has been always booting in graphical mode (KDE).

Few days ago it suddently started to boot in console mode, so that I have to insert manually login and password and finally execute the command

```
 startx
```

to run graphical environment.

If I try to press "e" (in grub, as I'm running Mint in dual boot with Win8.1) it brings me to grub config file and I can clearly see

```
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
```

So what's wrong?

**EDIT**: I also noticed that after login (either in console mode or in console afer running **startx**) the first printed line is:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/mint-fortune: No such file or directory
```

And I never got this error until the boot problem popped up

**EDIT 2** (updated)
mdm wasns't installed. so I installed it from graphical environment.

I checked Content of the file "/etc/X11/default-display-manager" which is

```
/usr/X11/mdm
```

I tried to run

```
 sudo service mdm start
```

which loads a very simple interface but after login the same interface as **startx** is loaded

Comment: Have you attempted to start the default display manager (probably `mdm`) i.e. `sudo service mdm start` instead of `startx`? Is `mdm` installed? What are the contents of the `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` file?

Comment: mdm wasns't installed. I installed it from graphical environment. Content of the file is "/usr/sbin/mdm". I tried to run "sudo service mdm start" it loads a very simple interface but after login the same interface as startx is loaded

Answer (score -1):

If you can run Linux in graphical mode check the file `/etc/inittab` and look for the line:

`id:5:initdefault:`

Maybe in your case there is a 3 there.

Comment: that file doesn't even exist in /etc/ . please see my updated question

Comment: You are right, I used the Red Hat file, for Linux Mint you can check [this guide](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels)

Comment: please just delete this, it's wrong.

Comment: Isaac, what should I seek in that very long page?